# Ruby on Rails MySQL DB Migration Aborting Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mysql, database-migration

I'm trying to import an existing database into a new rails application we are developing. I used `rake db:schema dump` to successfully dump the schema of my database. Whenever I try to dump my data using `rake db:data:dump`, rake aborts with the following output:

```
rake db:data:dump --trace
** Invoke db:data:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:data:dump
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0' at line 1: SELECT  * FROM `hypqd_akeeba_common`  ORDER BY key LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:297:in `query'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:297:in `block in execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:464:in `block in log'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:458:in `log'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:297:in `execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:225:in `execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:229:in `exec_query'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:340:in `select'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:184:in `block in each_table_page'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:182:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:182:in `each_table_page'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:47:in `dump_table_records'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:167:in `dump_table'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:150:in `block in dump'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:148:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:148:in `dump'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:14:in `dump'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0' at line 1
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:297:in `query'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:297:in `block in execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:464:in `block in log'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:458:in `log'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:297:in `execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:225:in `execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:229:in `exec_query'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:340:in `select'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:184:in `block in each_table_page'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:182:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:182:in `each_table_page'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/yaml_db.rb:47:in `dump_table_records'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:167:in `dump_table'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:150:in `block in dump'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:148:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:148:in `dump'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/serialization_helper.rb:14:in `dump'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/yaml_db-0.3.0/lib/tasks/yaml_db_tasks.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/awernick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:data:dump
```

I've checked my schema and I can't find anything related to syntax error ``` key LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0' at line 1: SELECT  * FROM ``hypqd_akeeba_common``  ORDER BY key LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0 ```

What is causing rake to abort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The issue had nothing to do with rake or even mysql. My database was not dumped correctly from the phpmyadmin original database. After redumping the database everything worked correctly.